# Start time of a process in QNX

Tags: process, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I tried to get the start time of a process in QNX using the **ps** command i.e. **ps -A -o "pid, stime, cmd"**, but it's showing the start time of all processes as **00.00** (seconds field is missing).

How to get start time of all processes in QNX using command ?

Comment: For QNX utilities, checking the logs using `slog2info` can be useful

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Linux, you can find your process ID by using `ps -aux | grep <process_name_here>` then you can type this command to show elapsed time (if the process is running): `ps -p <process_id_here> -o etime`